# ROS java android: Not a v4.0.0 POM

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
When I try to build android package on Ubuntu 10.0.4 with Electric.

```
android> hg log | head
changeset:   34:92c43d549bcd
tag:         tip
user:        Damon Kohler <damonkohler@google.com>
date:        Thu Sep 22 08:48:08 2011 +0200
summary:     Remove pan tilt example. This is essentially the same as the image transport or camera example.

android> rosmake android
```

I get this error:

```
maven-bug-workaround:
[artifact:pom] An error has occurred while processing the Maven artifact tasks.
[artifact:pom]  Diagnosis:
[artifact:pom]
[artifact:pom] Unable to initialize POM std_msgs-pom.xml: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project unknown at /home/yienyien/.ros/rosjava/maven/std_msgs-pom.xml
```

Because this error is not raised every time, I thought it was a race condition, I try to put sleep after pom generation here:

```
rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/python/rosjava_bootstrap/generate_msg.depends.py:154
```

but without sucess.

Thank you for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11411/ros-java-android:-not-a-v4.0.0-pom/) by [Yienyien](https://answers.ros.org/users/1164/yienyien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-10-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A couple things to try:

- Do a make clean everywhere, delete ~/.ros/rosjava, and rerun rosmake.
- Try rosmake with --threads=1. If that fixes it, it's a known issue, see http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/detail?id=63

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2011-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1